# Howto open html page in default browser, when html code is stored in QString

Tags: c++, qt, temporary-files

My Qt application should open a **html page** (with the default browser eg. IE). This html code is stored in a `QString`.

What would be the best way to open this "file", of which I only have the content?

Is `QTemporaryFile` the answer to this? Or could this be done easier?

```
QString content = "<html>...</html>";
?
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("..."));
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use [Qt Webkit](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html) to open page in your application?

Comment: The webpage that I want to show contains alot of complex redirects, downloads, etc. It's much easier to just use the default browser so the users can use an environment they know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QTemporaryFile approach is by far the easiest to accomplish your task.

I don't see any other way other then doing some "vodoo" with ActiveQt, if that works at all.

Best regards.

EDIT: An example

```
QString htmlData; // your HTML data here

// The six Xs are actually required.
QTemporaryFile tmpFile( QLatin1String( "thefileXXXXXX.html" ) );
tmpFile.open();
QTextStream out( &tmpFile )
out << htmlData;
tmpFile.close();
QDesktopServives::openUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( tmpFile.fileName() ) );
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to generate a temporary file with the content of this QString? It should have the extension ".html". There are only few examples of QTemporaryFile online and I don't get the basics of it :s

Comment: Did you try it? I'm afraid, it will not work, because `QTemporaryFile::close` [does not work](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/io/qtemporaryfile.cpp#line425)

Comment: @DariuszScharsig, the problem is that file may be locked and `QDesktopServives` will not be able to open it, while it still opened by `QTemporaryFile`. And when `QTemporaryFile` will be destroyed, file will be deleted also.

Comment: Yeah, but it's not blocked. QTemporaryFile::close() calls QFile::close() and it flushes the file, the browser can access it, since it's a read only access anyway. Even if the file is deleted, the browser is displaying it's contents. As said, I've tried it out. Works like a charm.

Comment: @DariuszScharsig, did you open the _link_?

Comment: The dir is allright, I didn't know that specifying the filename causes this behaviour. It looks like the file is not written to the hard drive, or that it was removed before the browser had time to open it. @DariuszScharsig, can you find the temporary file on your harddrive when running this script?

Comment: Yes, I could, at least right after it was created. The moment QTemporaryFile goes out of scope the file's gone. You could implement a little wait loop after calling the desktop services.

Comment: You are right! The file had been made, but was deleted before the browser could open it. Adding `QThread::msleep();` after calling QDesktopServives solved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: But I will search for an alternative for `QThread::msleep()` because this blocks the whole application